# Is this allowed in an array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, arraylist

I am trying to have a list of values separated by a comma like this:

```
$products = array( array( Title => "rose", 
                      Price => 1.25,1.31,1.54,1.39
                      //comma separated list
                      Type => dropdown
                    ),
               array( Title => "daisy", 
                      Price => 0.75,
                      Type => text_field,
                    ),
               array( Title => "orchid", 
                      Price => 1.15,
                      Type => text_field
                    )
             );
```

Is there a way i can items represent comma separated list in an array in php?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$products = array( array( Title => "rose", 
                      Price => array(1.25,1.31,1.54,1.39)
                      //comma separated list
                      Type => dropdown
                    ),
               array( Title => "daisy", 
                      Price => 0.75,
                      Type => text_field,
                    ),
               array( Title => "orchid", 
                      Price => 1.15,
                      Type => text_field
                    )
             );
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a comma separated list as a string, and want it represented as an array, you can use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
$myString = "1,2,3,4,5";
$myArray = explode(',',$myString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You have to assign "1.25,1.31,1.54,1.39" in to ARRAY as string(by enclosed with "")

Like -

```
$products = array( array( Title => "rose", 
                      Price => "1.25,1.31,1.54,1.39",
                      //comma separated list
                      Type => "dropdown"
                    ),
               array( Title => "daisy", 
                      Price => 0.75,
                      Type => text_field,
                    ),
               array( Title => "orchid", 
                      Price => 1.15,
                      Type => text_field
                    )
             );
```

Comment: I am now getting Notice: Use of undefined constant Title - assumed 'Title' in C:\wamp\www\serializer.php on line 2.

Comment: You have to write array index/key as string if it would not integer, for your example all of the array keys are string. So your have to write them as string. Title as "Title", Price as "Price" and so on

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign an array a comma-separated list because a pointer can only point to a memory not a structure. You can workaround by using another array or a string. When you want to to use a string you want to use the function explode() to separate the string.